# noncapturing group explanation within a positive lookahead

Tags: regex

Does this regular expression mean that at least one of the following that isn't a-z:

`(?=.*(?:[a-z]))`

It's part of the following expression:

```
/^(?=[A-Za-z0-9\'\s\d\.]{2,50}$)(?=.*(?:[a-z]))[a-zA-Z0-9]+[A-Za-z0-9\'\s\.]+$/m
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `(?=.*(?:[a-z]))` means that there could be whatever but must finish with a lowercase letter.

This regex means:

```
/^(?=[A-Za-z0-9\'\s\d\.]{2,50}$)(?=.*(?:[a-z]))[a-zA-Z0-9]+[A-Za-z0-9\'\s\.]+$/m
```

*Match the line that starts with 2 to 50 alphanumeric, single quote, spaces or a dot, and then follows with lower case letter, and continues with alphanumerics and must ends followed by alphanumerics, spaces, single quote or dot.*

Here you can see a better graphical approach for your regex:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Actually, this can be improved as:

```
/^(?=[A-Za-z\d'\s.]{2,50}$)(?=.*[a-z])[a-zA-Z\d]+[A-Za-z\d'\s.]+$/m
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: can you please elaborate on "AND follows with lower case letter,"

Comment: @jkushner I enphatized how your patterns were used lol, like "start with A and then x and then blablabla". Will update it

Comment: I understand. So what is the exact purpose of having the non-capturing group in here?

Comment: @jkushner nothing, it has no sense. That's why I added `this can be improved as` part.